# Multiple input data on same module ( Torus sections)

Tags: plotting

I am computing to show several sectional projections of a circular torus intersected by planes parallel to the torus axis of symmetry.

However the displacement $d$ is manually given here, so is laborious.

Please indicate the code for multiple input working on same macro, making the code more compact. Thanks in advance for the same.

```
Clear["`Global\*"]
R=1;c=1.6;
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (c+R Cos[u]),Sin[t] (c+R Cos[u]),Sin[u]},{t,0,2Pi},{u,0,2Pi},AxesLabel->{YY,ZZ,XX},PlotStyle->{Opacity[0.3]}]
d=0.2;
g2=ContourPlot[d==(R^2+c^2+2 c*Sqrt[R^2-x^2]-x^2-z^2)^0.5,{x,-2 R,2R},{z,-c-2R,c+2R},AxesLabel->{xx,zz},ContourStyle->Red]
g2N=ContourPlot[d==(R^2+c^2-2 c*Sqrt[R^2-x^2]-x^2-z^2)^0.5,{x,-2 R,2R},{z,-c-2R,c+2R},AxesLabel->{xx,zz},ContourStyle->Red]
d=1.0;
g1=ContourPlot[d==(R^2+c^2+2 c*Sqrt[R^2-x^2]-x^2-z^2)^0.5,{x,-2 R,2R},{z,-c-2R,c+2R},AxesLabel->{XX,ZZ},ContourStyle->Magenta];
g1N=ContourPlot[d==(R^2+c^2-2 c*Sqrt[R^2-x^2]-x^2-z^2)^0.5,{x,-2 R,2R},{z,-c-2R,c+2R},AxesLabel->{XX,ZZ},ContourStyle->Magenta];
d=1.5;
g15=ContourPlot[d==(R^2+c^2+2 c*Sqrt[R^2-x^2]-x^2-z^2)^0.5,{x,-2 R,2R},{z,-c-2R,c+2R},AxesLabel->{XX,ZZ},ContourStyle->Black];
g15N=ContourPlot[d==(R^2+c^2-2 c*Sqrt[R^2-x^2]-x^2-z^2)^0.5,{x,-2 R,2R},{z,-c-2R,c+2R},AxesLabel->{XX,ZZ},ContourStyle->Black];
d=c-R
gcR=ContourPlot[d==(R^2+c^2+2 c*Sqrt[R^2-x^2]-x^2-z^2)^0.5,{x,-2 R,2R},{z,-c-2R,c+2R},AxesLabel->{XX,ZZ},ContourStyle->Black]
gcRN=ContourPlot[d==(R^2+c^2-2 c*Sqrt[R^2-x^2]-x^2-z^2)^0.5,{x,-2 R,2R},{z,-c-2R,c+2R},AxesLabel->{XX,ZZ},ContourStyle->Black]
d=2.5;
g25=ContourPlot[d==(R^2+c^2+2 c*Sqrt[R^2-x^2]-x^2-z^2)^0.5,{x,-2 R,2R},{z,-c-2R,c+2R},AxesLabel->{XX,ZZ},ContourStyle->Green]
g25N=ContourPlot[d==(R^2+c^2-2 c*Sqrt[R^2-x^2]-x^2-z^2)^0.5,{x,-2 R,2R},{z,-c-2R,c+2R},AxesLabel->{XX,ZZ},ContourStyle->Green]
d=2.57;
g257=ContourPlot[d==(R^2+c^2+2 c*Sqrt[R^2-x^2]-x^2-z^2)^0.5,{x,-2 R,2R},{z,-c-2R,c+2R},AxesLabel->{XX,ZZ},ContourStyle->Purple]
g257N=ContourPlot[d==(R^2+c^2-2 c*Sqrt[R^2-x^2]-x^2-z^2)^0.5,{x,-2 R,2R},{z,-c-2R,c+2R},AxesLabel->{XX,ZZ},ContourStyle->Purple]
Show[{g1,g1N,g2,g2N,g15,g15N,g25,g25N,gcR,gcRN,g257,g257N},PlotLabel->{XX,ZZ},AspectRatio->2.6,PlotRange->All]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can only use the first `ParametricPlot3D`.

```
R = 1; c = 1.6;
Ysectionals = {.2, 1., 1.5, c - R, 2.5, 2.57};
colors = {Red, Magenta, Black, Black, Green, Purple};
data = Thread[{Join[Ysectionals, -Ysectionals], Join[colors, colors]}];
plot = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t]   (c + R   Cos[u]), 
    Sin[t]   (c + R   Cos[u]), Sin[u]}, {t, 0, 2  Pi}, {u, 0, 2  Pi}, 
   AxesLabel -> {XX, YY, ZZ}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {data},
    PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
   ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", ViewPoint -> {0, 1, 0}, 
   PlotStyle -> None, Axes -> {Automatic, None, Automatic}];
Graphics[plot[[1]] /. {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, z}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"XX", "ZZ"},RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice graphics modifying basic ParametricPlot3D. ( Btw, can we also label axes (ZZ,XX) )?

Comment: @Narasimham  Add `FrameLabel -> {"XX", "ZZ"}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
R = 1; c = 1.6;

dlist = {.2, 1., 1.5, c - R, 2.5, 2.57};

colorlist = {Red, Magenta, Black, Black, Green, Purple};
```

Define a function that takes two arguments, contour level `d` and color, and constructs a contour plot:

```
CP = ContourPlot[
    {# == (R^2 + c^2 + 2  c*Sqrt[R^2 - x^2] - x^2 - z^2)^0.5, 
     # == (R^2 + c^2 - 2  c*Sqrt[R^2 - x^2] - x^2 - z^2)^0.5}, 
    {x, -2  R, 2 R}, {z, -c - 2 R, c + 2 R}, 
    ContourStyle -> #2] &;

Show[MapApply[CP] @ Transpose[{dlist, colorlist}], 
 PlotLabel -> {XX, ZZ}, AspectRatio -> 2.6, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]